# Disable horizontal scroll on parallax

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, stellar.js

I made a site parallax scrolling, using slider and stellarjs. 
This works well for scrolling up and down, but it also scrolls horizontally and I do not want.

So i want to disable horizontally scrolling and keep my width at 100% of user screen or at a specific width.

here's the website : ecolopeintre.com/index_para.php

Comment: SAME problem... any news?

Answer (score 0):

Stellar offers options, please review docs http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/

In order to turn off horizontal scrolling please review the code below hopefully it can help.

```
$.stellar({
  horizontalScrolling: false,
});
```