# Disable Horizontal Scrolling Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, horizontal-scrolling, stellar.js

I have a weird issue with horizontal scrolling to the right

- I already made html/body width max at 100% and overflow-x hidden
- no elements outside viewport or negative margins to the right
- this issue isn't present on desktop
- meta user-scalable=no
- horizontal scrolling is set to false for stellar.js [Disable horizontal scroll on parallax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091264/disable-horizontal-scroll-on-parallax/)

I honestly can't think of any reason why and this issue is only on android.
http://bit.ly/1v0jVlh

Comment: What devices have you tested on? It doesn't seem to happen on a Nexus 5

Comment: I'm using browserstack live for testing.

Answer (score 1):

When using iScroll with Stellar.js it has css .mobile #wrapper, you must remove position absolute if you care to have it work for android.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css in your sheet (for mobile), it will disable the horizontal scrolling but would allow vertical scrolling.

```
body{
    postion: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
html{
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```